# Translate loop in numpy methods

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, vectorization

I need to get the cumulative maximum of array `longband` until its `[i-1]` value is `>=` of `RsiMa[i]`, then turn to its "real" `[i]` value and restart cumulating.
Actually the only way I found to achieve this is by a for loop.
Is it translatable to numpy?
How can I convert it?

THE CODE:

```
import numpy as np
RsiMa = np.array([   2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 10, 8])
longband = np.array([1, 3, 2, 8, 7,  5, 4, 3, 4, 3,  7, 10,  7, 6])

for i in range(1, len(longband)):
    if i > 1:
        if longband[i-1] > longband[i] and longband[i-1] < RsiMa[i]:
            longband[i] = longband[i-1]
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
[ 1  3  3  8  8   5  5  3  4  4  7  10  7  7 ]
```

I already tried with np.fmax.accumulate() but seems like it can't be restarted when `longband[i] >= RsiMa[i]`...

**EDIT:**
I tried also with numba jit:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def loop(array1, arrayfilt):
    for i in range(2, len(array1)):
        if array1[i-1] > array1[i] and array1[i-1] <= arrayfilt[i]:
            array1[i] = array1[i-1]
    return array1
longband = loop(longband, RsiMa)
```

but IDK why, instead of accelerating it, it cause a slowdown from 15ms of the simple loop to 33ms of jit...

Comment: There is no recursion here: no function calling itself. It is just a code with data dependencies on previous iterations. I am no sure there is a way to do that in Numpy (there might be a way to do it but certainly a complicated and inefficient one). I would personally use Numba/Cython for such a use-case. The `if i > 1` is not needed since you can just start the loop from `2`.

Comment: Thanks, edited. Anyway I'm interested to know a numpy solution :)

Comment: Awesome question to be honest. I wanted to jump in with simple and wrong solution. Got me thinking... Thanks!

Comment: Why start at index 2 (the second element is ignored)? Without this additional requirement, it is relatively straightforward (but still of no practical use) to implement an O(n^2) vectorized solution.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny well, I could roll the array to get [i-1], anyway could you provide your solution in answer?

Comment: Note that `np.vectorize` do not really vectorise things. It just do a loop calling a Python function which is pretty inefficient in practice. It is only useful for convenience, but not performance. I think your code is not equivalent to the original one since the original one can perform many copy and there is possible dependency chain while this is not present in the new code (only a shift of 1, no more). In general, I do not think you can use np.vectorize for that unless if you do many shift in the vectorized function which is horribly inefficient (as MichaelSzczesny pointed out)

Comment: The Numba code needs to be compiled during the first run. You can compile it eagerly by using signature (please read the doc about that: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jit.html#eager-compilation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method do not prodice any improvement, but at least works:

```
###  vector function  ###
def vect(array1, array2, counter):
    if (array1[counter-1] > array1[counter] and array1[counter-1] < array2):
        array1[counter] = array1[counter-1]
    return array1[counter]

vvect = np.vectorize(vect, excluded=['array1'])
longband = vvect(array1=longband, array2=RsiMa, counter=np.arange(0, len(longband)))
OUTPUT: [ 1  3  3  8  8   5  5  3  4  4  7  10  7  7 ]
```

Comment: This solution is ~5x slower for larger arrays (up to ~13x slower for small arrays, removing the redundant `if` makes it even more pronounced) than the loop and gives different results, eg. for `longband = np.array([1, 0, 2, 8, 7,  5, 4, 3, 4, 3,  7, 10,  7, 6])`, because it is not excluding the second element.